# Dividing items into columns

Tags: c#

I have a dynamic number of items to divide into a maximum of 4 columns, with the proper html format surrounding then, lets say:

```
string[] s = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" }; // from 1 to n itens
```

To format into this html:

```
<ul>
  <li>
     1
     2
     3
  </li>
  <li>
     4
     5
  </li>
  <li>
     6
     7
  </li>
  <li>
     8
     9
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Edit: my website problem:**

If you have words as itens, putting the itens this way will organize the words into alphabetically columns (people read this way), not alphabetically rows. Like:

```
a d g i
b e h j
c f
```

Instead of:

```
a b c d
e f g h
i j
```

Comment: Why has the first list 3 items whereas the others have only two? Is this ASP.NET?

Comment: You probably have more requirements than that otherwise it would be trivial (for example, 1 is less than 4 -> always use 1 column). Your example also looks like you have more requirements.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Because I have 9 itens. And I can't put 2.25 itens in each column. If I have 10 itens, the first two columns will get 5 itens.

Comment: @harold It's why I said "maximum of 4 columns". If you have 1, 2 or 3 itens you will have only 1, 2 or 3 columns respectively.

Comment: @DavidStratton flaged as rude and offensive.

Comment: @user1330271 if you have a maximum of 4 columns, that means that 1 columns is allowed, because 1 is less than the maximum. If that's not an acceptable solution, that means there has to be some other requirement as well - something you haven't told us yet.

Comment: @user1330271 there's not. You can have from 1 to 4 columns, from 1 to n elements, each columns get the same amount of itens, unless you don't have a multiple of 4, in which case the column to the left get more itens.

Comment: @user1330271 so then you can use 1 column with n elements, then every column automatically has the same number of elements (namely n).

Comment: @harold quit busting his balls about the requirements. Obviously he needs the items evenly distributed between the columns.

Comment: @user1330271  Huh?  Rude or offensive because I asked if it was homework?  OK.  I didn't mean to be rude, just asking.  Sorry if it came across that way.  Usually when I want to be rude it's a bit more obvious.  ;-)

Comment: @DavidStratton A rhetorical question is a figure of speech in the form of a question that is asked in order to make a point and without the expectation of a reply. (from wikipedia)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you want to evenly distribute any remainders, this will do the job:

```
string[] s = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };

// create the 4 buckets with equal distribution
var buckets = Enumerable.Repeat(s.Length / 4, 4).ToArray();

// distribute any remainders evenly starting from the first bucket
var rem = s.Length % 4; 
for (var i = 0; i < rem; i++) buckets[i]++;

var idx = 0;
Console.WriteLine("<ul>");
foreach (var bucket in buckets)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\t<li>");
    foreach (var _ in Enumerable.Range(1, bucket))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t\t{0}", s[idx++]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\t</li>");
}
Console.WriteLine("</ul>");
```

---

For the above code, here is what some edge cases return.

`{}` = 4 empty items in list

`{ "1", "2", "3"}` = 1, 2, 3 in the first three items, fourth item empty

`{ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}` = 1, 2 in the first item, 3, 4, 5 in the other items

Comment: Note I tested with your original array and it works. I also tested with the array shown in the above answer (added an extra element at the front) and can confirm the first two 'buckets' end up with an extra element as expected.

Comment: I got a out of range exception. But I'll work my way over your code. Thx.

Comment: I updated the code, there was a small bug. What array are you using?

Comment: Yeah I found another bug caused by fixing the other one, all good now. Test cases shown.

Comment: it does exactly what I need. Nice one. I started coding some lines end ended up with a spaghetti monster. At the beggining seems easy to solve, but it's not, at least for me. Thank you again. I'll work my ass to understand what you did there now. Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

Just loop over the array distributing the array items with a few if statements within it.

```
int j = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
{
    if (j == 0)
      // put s[i] in column 1 j = j +1
    else if (j == 1)
      // put s[i] in column 2 j = j +1
    else if (j == 2)
      // put s[i] in column 3 j = j +1
    if (j == 3)
      // put s[i] in column 4 set j = 0
}
```

Comment: j is always 0, so the itens are all in the first column.

Comment: The itens will not be in the order I need then to be. But hey, thx.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to group by columns instead of rows, just realize that you're ultimately going to have to do SOMETHING with the index. The easiest way to do this is to transform the items into Item/Index pairs and group by those indexes somehow.

```
s.Select((tr, ti) => new { Index = ti, Item = tr })
 .GroupBy(tr => tr.Index % SOME_MAGIC_NUMBER)
```

If you want to instead group by rows, change the `%` operator to a division `/` and you'll be set. This will now take all your items and group them into the however many items you specify (based on either row or column). To transform them, all you have to do is another select:

```
.Select(tr => "<li>" + string.Join(" ", tr.Select(tstr => tstr.Item.ToString()).ToArray()) + "</li>")
```

This will get you a list of all your list items in whatever format you want. If you want to include `<br />` between the elements of each `<li>` then just change the first argument of the `string.Join` call.

Comment: This doesn't guarantee what he needs does it? Specifically, if the magic number is 4 and there are 5 in total (assuming `Index` is actually `Index + 1`): `%` will put the fifth one in the first column, whereas he wants the second one in the first column.

Comment: Ahh, indeed. Lemme tinker some more, I'm sure it can be done.

Comment: I tried this method and ended up going somewhat imperative for a simpler approach. Basically you want to size each column first, and always ensure you have four columns. Then you can probably do something clever with index, mod, group by, and your sizing list to decide where each element goes.

Comment: @SPFiredrake our colegue yamen wrote a code that does the job. I want to thank you anyways for trying to help me.

Comment: Agreed, didn't realize it was also adding the additional column, so this was a knee-jerk reaction. However, it might be doable by transposing the data...